# VideoJS currentTime() always returning 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I'm using videoJs to load a video into an admin 
platform built in react. I set up the player here :

```
else if (contentSource == 'arclight'){
  var options = {
    height:'216',
    sources :[{
    //src: this.state.video.url,
  //  type: 'video/mp4'
  }]
  }
  var player = videojs('player',options,function onPlayerReady() {
    videojs.log('Your player is ready!');
  })
  this.setState({
    player:player,content: contentSource
  });
}
```

My video is displayed in this  tag :

```
<video id="player" class="player"
className={`video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered 
${styles.vjs}`}
controls preload= "auto" data-
setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src={this.state.video.url} type= "video/mp4" />
<p className="vjs-no-js">
To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider 
upgrading to a web browser that
<a href= "http://videojs.com/html5-video-support"  
target="_blank"> supports HTML5 video </a>
</p>
</video>
```

and lastly i'm trying to get the current time of the video that is playing in this method

```
handleCurrentButton(inputId, event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var timeMark =0;
  if(this.state.content == 'vimeo'){
    this.state.player.getCurrentTime().then(function(seconds){console.log(seconds)
      timeMark=seconds;
      VideosActions.updateVideoAttribute(inputId, timeMark);
  }).catch(function(error){
  });
}
  else if(this.state.content == 'youtube') {
    timeMark = Math.round(this.state.player.getCurrentTime());
    VideosActions.updateVideoAttribute(inputId, timeMark);
}

else {
//  timeMark = this.state.player.currentTime();
  console.log(this.state.player.currentTime())
  VideosActions.updateVideoAttribute(inputId, timeMark);
}
}
```

the problem is that the player.currentTime() call is always returning 0. The other two getCurrentTime's for Vimeo and Youtube work fine. what is the reason behind this? I tried to give enough context around this problem so that you would be able to figure it out.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is getCurrentTime() returns a promise so you need to access the value of the time when the promise is resolved as a callback to the Promise's `.then()` function.

```
else {

  this.state.player.currentTime().then(function(seconds){
    console.log(seconds)
    timeMark=seconds;
    VideosActions.updateVideoAttribute(inputId, timeMark);
  });

}
```

Comment: per the videojs documentation I believe that it doesn't return a promise. http://docs.videojs.com/Player.html#currentTime  : the documentation says that it should return a number?

Comment: From that it looks like you're right but I was looking at your vimeo example which looks like a promise.   You're using it differently in Vimeo and YouTube but they both work?

Comment: Yeah the vimeo and youtube both work. They are different because i'm using the vimeo and youtube players for both of them respectively. vimeo is a promise, so i have to use `.then` but youtube's getCurrent time returns a number.  The third player that i have is for a content source that doesn't have it's own custom player like vimeo and youtube do

Answer (score 0):

Worth making sure your server returning 206 response on the video HTTP request, otherwise players dont handle seek well.

Comment: It would be very helpful for the SO if you could post a code sample.